# WHy is WAMP not working?

Tags: wamp

I'm trying to teach myself web development, but I cannot seem to get wamp to work. I have Installed the program and after changing the port I now get a green logo.

The tutorial tells me to double click on the index.php file in the www directory of the WAMP program files, this gives me this.

[image]

I'm then told to change the address from

file:///C:/wamp/www/index.php to localhost/index.php, but when I do I just get a blank page.

[image]

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank You.

Comment: try this http://localhost/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing good,

you did put your server online and access the index.php successfully.

The main problem is that you didn't use "echo" in php to print anything on the page or write any html code so the browser cannot render anything.

Try to copy and website source code or as simple as follow:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work as a web page as expected.

Remeber,if you changed port no. in the config file, please change the URL to

localhost:portno/index.php such as localhost:8080/index.php

Comment: Aah brilliant that last sentence is the part I missed. The moment I typed localhost:333/index.php I got the WAMP menu I was looking for. Thank You very much.

Comment: You are welcome! I also just started learning about web. Feel free to ask question, we are going to help you asap

Comment: This answer I am afraid is complete nonsense, apart form the last line. All that was required is to use the browser properly and NOT click on a .php file using Explorer as that will not load the php file via Apache i.e. you web browser